# The this number mean in Browser support section in mdn

Tags: javascript, html, css, mdns

I have worked a little bit on the web, and sometimes I have to go back and look up some properties or methods in MDN, but I found in the browser support section some numbers I couldn't understand, and I have hope to get some help here.

---

[image]

---

I understand that green box in a browser means it supports it but I see inside of it some numbers I hope someone explains it for me

Comment: The numbers represent the Browser Version so the methods is supported if the browser version is higher than the number represented

Comment: for that font-family is supported by google chrome for the first version right?

Comment: Yes it is and edge from version 12 ...

Comment: could you write an answer down and I will let your answer to be the answer to my question because I don't want to leave the question open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers represent the Browser Version so the methods is supported if the browser version is higher than the number represented

So you can see what works with some browser versions by that chart .Mozilla keeps the list up to date with anything script that works with the firefox browser including Javascript and CSS tags .

Web technology is consistently growing and its resourceful feature to keep your code compliant with certain browser versions .

Web developers use that list  to determine if their code will work with the majority of browsers .

Different web browsers had different implementations of code because of the browser wars . And Microsoft in specific did not want to come to consensus of other browsers during the early 90.s

[Browser Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_wars)